# How can I divide HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

Here is the code:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> arr = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 
arr.put("one", 1); 
arr.put("two", 2); 
arr.put("three", 3);
```

how can I to get all strings as String[] array and all integers as Int[] array?

---

thanks to all! all is correct, if somebody has the same Problemm, answer is:

```
String[] entry =(String[])arr.keySet().toArray(new String[arr.size()]);
Integer[] entry_values =(Integer[])arr.values().toArray(new Integer[arr.size()]);
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293946/the-easiest-way-to-transform-collection-to-array

Comment: and get the keys by i think the command is .keySet() and values by calling values() but im not sure if the commands are exactly that

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960265/retrieve-all-values-from-hashmap-keys-in-an-arraylist-java

Comment: if you would have googled it, you would have had thousands results on this, and this is not even related to android. No offence.

Answer (score 2):

1) `arr.keySet().toArray(new String[arr.size()]);`

2) `arr.values().toArray(new Integer[arr.size()]);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `keySet()` and `values()` methods to get the strings and integers alone. They both return collections, so you can then call `toArray` on them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Method to get your Items by their type, but by their function in the map.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> arr = new HashMap<String, Integer>();     
Set<String> keys = arr.keySet(); // all keys.
Collection<Integer> values = arr.values(); //all values.
```

you can call `toArray()` on both of your results. Add a new Array as argument to define the type of the result.

```
String[] strings = keys.toArray(new String[arr.size()]);
Integer[] ints = values.toArray(new Integer[arr.size()]);
```

Comment: by String[] strings = keys.toArray(new String[]);
have I a Error java: array dimension missing

Comment: you can add any size, if the size is to small a new array with the right dimension is created. Adding the right dimension saves this operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
String strArr[] = new String[arr.size()];
arr.keySet().toArray(strArr); // Populate the String array with map keys

Integer intArr[] = new Integer[arr.size()];
arr.values().toArray(intArr); // Populate the Int array with map values
```